# Summarize a table based on a column in another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables in Power BI model

**Table A**

- value1
- value2
- value3
- ....
- value 1000

**Table B**

- value 1  |  10
- value 2  |  10
- value 1  |  50
- value 3  |  10
- value 1  | -10
- value 2  |  70

Can I make a new column (or measure) in Table A to Sum UP connected values ???

Expected RESULT:

- value 1  |  50   ---  *(10+50-10)*
- value 2  |  80   ---  *(10+70)*
- value 3  |  10   ---  *(10)*

Just something like SUM.IF in Excel, which can I drag to all rows ? Thanks in advance.

I tried to CALCULATE, but I can't do this for all different rows in Table A

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Table A` for this. SUMMARIZE() will create a column of distinct values to group by. Use the following **Calculated Table**. Note that this is NOT a MEASURE!

```
Result = 
SUMMARIZE(
   'Table B',
   'Table B'[value ID],
   "Sum", SUM('Table B'[number])
)
```

[image]

Comment: ERROR: The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value. (Wyrażenie odwołuje się do wielu kolumn. Nie można przekonwertować wielu kolumn na wartość skalarną)

Comment: Answering your questions is effort. So please take your time and read the answer carefully. I put it in **bold** that the expression results in a **calculated table**, so you have to paste it into the "New Table" GUI. Your error message indicates that you've been using the "New Measure" GUI instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Possible ! Just Add a new column on your table, and write this DAX Code after relationship is created!

[image: Final Result]